# Expectation value of random variable conditionally defined

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For some $Y, Z$ random variables and $p \in [0, 1]$, consider the random variable $X$ defined as follows

$$ X = \begin{cases} Y & \text{with probability } p \\
Z & \text{with probability } 1-p\end{cases} $$

My question is how do I go on to find $E[X]$? I have a feeling that it should
look like:
$$ E[X] = pE[Y] + (1-p)E[Z] $$

But I am unable to prove it. I would be grateful for any hints on the proof.

Ultimatly I want to find the expected value of a random variable $X$ defined as such for random variables $A, B, C$ and boolean predicate $r$

$$ X = \begin{cases} A & \text{if } r(C) \\
B & \text{if } \neg r(C) \end{cases}$$

which I guess would be something like this

$$ E[X] = \Pr[r(C)] \cdot E[A] + \Pr[\neg r(C)] \cdot E[B]$$

Here's my proof of the second expected value expression assuming
the first expected value expression is correct. Let $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(C)$
then
\begin{align*} E[X] &=
E[E[X\mid \mathcal{F}]]\\&= E[A \cdot \Pr[r(C)] + B \cdot \Pr[\neg r(C)]] \\
&= \Pr[r(C)] \cdot E[A] + \Pr[\neg r(C)] \cdot E[B] \end{align*}

Comment: I am not sure if this is the proof you want. Just express $X = WY + (1 - W)Z$ where $W$ is a Bernoulli($p$) random variable, independent to $Y, Z$.

Comment: @BGM Yes, thank you! that's exactly what I was looking for. If you could write up an answer I'll select it as the best answer.

Comment: The hypothesis as written here does not imply the independence so crucial in @BGM's construction, hence the identity E(X)=pE(Y)+(1-p)E(Z) is far from being guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express
$$ X = WY + (1 - W)Z $$
where $W \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$ and independent of $Y, Z$. Then taking expectation, and by independence, you immediately obtain the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally true that $\operatorname{E}(\operatorname{E}(X\mid W)) = \operatorname{E}(X)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $\operatorname{E}(|X|)<\infty$.  This is sometimes called the "law of total expectation".  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) about it.

One can define $\operatorname{E}(X\mid W)$ as follows.  The conditional expected value of $X$ given an event $W=w$ is just ordinary conditioning on an event.  It gives you some function of $w$, thus $\operatorname{E}(X\mid W=w) = h(w)$.  Then $\operatorname{E}(X\mid W)$ is $g(W)$.  Hence $\operatorname{E}(X\mid W) = \operatorname{E}(g(W))$.